# Get all dependencies path for all configurations

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I need to get paths to all dependencies in all configurations. I tried to do it like this:

```java
    private Set<String> collectDependencies() {
        Set<String> dependencies = new HashSet<>();
            for (Configuration configuration : getProject().getConfigurations()) {
                    for (File dependency : configuration.getFiles()) {
                        try {
                            if ("jar".equals(getFileExtension(dependency))) dependencies.add(dependency.toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            if (enableStacktrace) logger.lifecycle("oh shit", e);
                        }
                    }
            }

        return dependencies;
    }
```

But this leads to this error:
`Resolving configuration 'apiElements' directly is not allowed`

How can i fix this? What am I doing wrong? Maybe I don’t understand something? Thank in advance.

Comment: This comment can give some background as to why you're facing that issue: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/3-4-rc-1-3-3-resolving-configurations-may-be-disallowed-and-throw-illegalstateexception/21470/2

Comment: @FranciscoMateo thx for you reply. But i need just list of pathes to all dependency in all configuration. "gradle dependency" give me this list but without pathes. And no need to resolve something. How to just get dependency pathes without any resolving?